# Problem to install my addon on blender without use __init__

Tags: scripting, add-on

I made a little addon with a library. My problem is i have 2 version for 2.79 and 2.8
I would like to call the .py file in a recognizable way for example `addon_2.8.py` and `addon_2.79.py` but this case addon not work ... addon is a single module/file .py and the only way to make it work is call it `__init__.py` (this is confusing about the distribution of my addon)

Comment: Lose the period in the file name. Trying to run `import addon_2.8` will throw an error. Something like `some_sane_name28x.py` and `27x`.

Comment: Very sorry @batFINGER not understand. Is single file .py  , but i try some without "." name but nothing changes. It only work if name is __init__.py (with double underline) look on top for correct name

Comment: any idea because work only with init? is the same problem in 2.79 and 2.8

Comment: If it is in a folder needs an `__init__.py` Basically an addon is like any other other python module.  Check the python docs on setting up a module.  If its a folder in `__init__.py` put a version test and `import foo_bar_version as foo_bar`  then  in register method `foo_bar.register()`.   Also check addons folders for examples of techniques that successfully install.  (To clarify single file is py file installed to addons folder, not a folder with single file.)

Comment: Ok it is the problem. But if install the addon not in a single folder when i unistall from preferences , unistall only module .py but the library it is not deleted

Comment: If this "library" is contained in a folder, recommend it be in addon folder and hence need an `__init__.py`  lol.

Comment: From preferences-add-ons "Remove" button (Delete the add-ons from the file system) but delete only the module .py not the library folder. But if install in a single folder with "init" name "Remove" work fine